# How to architect the DAPP blockchain EVM app?

Tags: architecture, blockchain, ethereum, decentralized-applications

I am developing the blockchain based application it is basically a ledger system to track who owns the item now. I want to ask where that item information comes from will it be keep in some centralized database and then I will do the tracking of that item/product in blockchain ? And Where do I keep the customer or CSR user in blockchain or it will also be keep in database what about their private and public key. where do I keep it in RDB?
Is this the right approach .
Kindly help thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing data in blockchain is expensive. Secondly blockchain is a public ledger of Information, which means whatever you store in blockchain can be seen by anyone so storing personal data in blockchain is not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks Ahmed, Can you tell me where should I then store the product data and user data will I be keeping that in Relational database ? or NoSQL ?
In centralized place ?

Comment: I can answer more general on that as i dont know alot About the requirements. So storing data in blockchain will cost you some amount. Every time you store a product it will cost you, further whenever you want to update the product quantity it will also cost you some amount. Further blockchain is used for the payment process.

Comment: wait what for payment ? Not necessary it is also used for tracking record like ledger of assets people are developing Decentralized App.

Comment: Johnny as i said i don't know a lot about requirement, if you can handle the amount on updating data in blockchain you can use it for storing information too

Comment: @JohnnyMartin can you mark the answer correct if you get the answer. Thanks